# Why isn't Django using the prefix from my root URLconf when reversing URLs?

Tags: django, url, reverse

Suppose I have a Django project that looks like this:

```
- project
   - urls.py
   - items
      - urls.py
      - views.py
```

The root URLconf looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?:items/)?$', include('items.urls')),
)
```

The URLconf for items looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('items.views',
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'view'),
)
```

`views.py` contains a method:

```
def view(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)
    return render(request, 'item/view.html', {'item': item})
```

I'm trying to use [`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) in Django's interactive shell but it isn't working:

```
>>> reverse('items.views.view', kwargs={'item_id': 12})
'/12/'
```

The problem is that the reversed URL is missing the `items/` prefix from the root URLconf. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to use name in url? ex: url(...... , name='items-view'), and use reverse('items-view', args=[12])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was doing something dumb:

```
url(r'^(?:items/)?$', include('items.urls')),
```

Because the 'items' is optional, the `reverse` method just ignores it and outputs '/'.